# Não consigo enviar os dados da minha App para a base de dados

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Ola tenho tido alguns problemas com a minha base de dados SQlite no Android Studio quando tento adicionar um novo utilizador ele não faz a inserção e apresentando a mensagem de erro na inserção dos utilizadores. Segundo o que falei com alguns colegas nenhum deles viu o porque de não esta a enviar.

Se alguém me conseguisse ajudar ficaria muito grato obrigado

**DatabaseOpenHelpe.java**

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelpe extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseOpenHelpe( Context context ) {
        super(context,"default", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table Users(" +
                "iduser integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "username text," +
                "password text,"+
                "email text)");

        db.execSQL("create table Restaurante(" +
                "idrestaurante integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "restaurante text, " +
                "lugares int)");

        db.execSQL("create table Reservas(" +
                "idreserva integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "reserva text," +
                "iduser integer," +
                "idrestaurante integer, " +
                "foreign key(iduser) references Users(iduser)," +
                "foreign key(idrestaurante) references Restaurante(idrestaurante))");

        db.execSQL("insert into restaurante(idrestaurante,restaurante,lugares) values('0','Cabana do Pastor','70')",null);
        db.execSQL("insert into restaurante(idrestaurante,restaurante,lugares) values('1','Sushi Pra ti','40')",null);
        db.execSQL("insert into restaurante(idrestaurante,restaurante,lugares) values('2','Dom Fininho','60')",null);
        db.execSQL("insert into restaurante(idrestaurante,restaurante,lugares) values('3 ','Marques de Marialva','60')",null);
        db.execSQL("insert into restaurante(idrestaurante,restaurante,lugares) values('4','Marisqueira C3','50')",null);
        db.execSQL("insert into restaurante(idrestaurante,restaurante,lugares) values('5','Restaurante Júlia Duarte','70')",null);
        db.execSQL("insert into restaurante(idrestaurante,restaurante,lugares) values('6','Bar Necal','60')",null);
        db.execSQL("insert into restaurante(idrestaurante,restaurante,lugares) values('7','Cova do Finfas','50')",null);
        db.execSQL("insert into restaurante(idrestaurante,restaurante,lugares) values('8','Pitada de Sal','50')",null);
        db.execSQL("insert into restaurante(idrestaurante,restaurante,lugares) values('9','La Bella Capricciosa','50')",null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users");
    }

    public long CriarUtilizadores(String username, String password, String email){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase ();
        db.execSQL("insert into users(username,password,email) values(?,?,?);",new String[]{username,password,email});
        return 0;
    }

    public String validarlogin(String username, String password ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase ();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery ( "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username=? AND password=?",new String[]{username, password});
        if (c.getCount ()>0){
            return "Ok";
        }
        return "ERRO";
    }

}
```

**Register.java**

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username, pass1, pass2, mail;
    Button bt_confirmar;
    DatabaseOpenHelpe db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_register );

        db = new DatabaseOpenHelpe ( this );

        username = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.rusername );
        mail = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.email );
        pass1 = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.rpassword1 );
        pass2= (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.rpassword2 );

        bt_confirmar = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.bt_confirmar );

        bt_confirmar.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String user = username.getText ().toString ();
                String email = mail.getText().toString();
                String p1 = pass1.getText().toString ();
                String p2 = pass1.getText().toString ();

                if(user.equals ("")){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Utilizador não inserido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    return;
                }
                if(p1.equals ( "" ) || p2.equals ( "" )){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Password não inserida",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    return;
                }
                if (!p1.equals( p2 )){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"As palavras pass não correspondem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    return;
                }
                if (email.equals ( "" )){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Email não inserido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    return;
                }
                long res = db.CriarUtilizadores ( user, p1, email );
                    if (res>0){
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Registado com sucesso",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Falha ao registrar, tente novamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Publique também o erro que aparece no log. Vai ajudar demais.

Answer (score 0):

A validação da criação do novo utilizador é feita verificando se o retorno do método  `CriarUtilizadores()` retorna um valor maior que zero.
Da forma como está, o método retorna sempre zero.

Altere o método para:

```
public long CriarUtilizadores(String username, String password, String email){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase ();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("username", "username");
    values.put("password", "password");
    values.put("email", "email");
    return db.insert("users", null, values);
}
```

Substitui o método `execSQL()` por [insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) porque este retorna -1 caso um erro tenha ocorrido. Em caso de sucesso retorna o id do registo inserido.